# Synchronised VS Striped Lock

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I have a class that is accessed by multiple threads, and I want to make sure it's thread safe. Plus it needs to be as fast as possible. This is just an example:

```
public class SharedClass {
  private final Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
  private final Striped<ReadWriteLock> rwLockStripes = Striped.readWriteLock(100);

  public void setSomethingFastVersion(String key, String value) {
    ReadWriteLock rwLock = rwLockStripes.get(key);
    try {
      rwLock.lock();
    } finally{
      rwLock.unLock();
    }

    data.put(key, value);
  }

  public synchronized void setSomethingSlowVersion(String key, String value) {
    data.put(key, value);
  }
}
```

I'm using `StripedLock` from Google Guava in one version, and a normal `synchronized` on the other one.

Am I right saying that the Guava version should be faster?

If so, what would be a good use case for `synchronized`, where the `StripedLocks` would not fit?

BTW, I know I could use a simple `ConcurrentHashMap` here, but I'm adding the example code to make sure you understand my question.

Comment: First, your `data.put(k,v)` needs to be inside your `try` block. 

Generally, managed, specific locks are faster than synchronization. Benchmarking will determine if that's true in your case. You're also using a ReadWrite lock here. Do you need that behavior? I don't see any reads here, how would you implement them?

Comment: @WillD what can you use instead of a `ReadWriteLock` then?

Comment: [ReentrantLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html)

Comment: Something else to consider here is whether you need to lock/sychronize at all. Even synchronized like this, the last caller sets the value. If you can't control the method access order, you can't be certain of results. Generally we lock on a map to make sure that nothing changes between a `get(k)` and a `put(k,v)` based on some function of the `get(k)`. Methods like `putIfAbsent()` on `ConcurrentMap` do the locking internally for you, but `put(k,v)` is not concurrent.

Answer (score 7):

Synchronized has been around for ages. It's not really surprising that we nowadays have more advanced mechanisms for concurrent programming.

However striped locks are advantageous only in cases where something can be partitioned or striped, such as locking parts of a map allowing different parts to be manipulated at the same time, but blocking simultaneous manipulations to the same stripe. In many cases you don't have that kind of partitioning, you're just looking for a mutex. In those cases `synchronized` is still a viable option, although a `ReadWriteLock` might be a better choice depending on the situation.

A `ConcurrentHashMap` has internal partitioning similar to stripes, but it applies only to the map operations such as `put()`. With an explicit `StripedLock` you can make longer operations atomic, while still allowing concurrency when operations don't touch the same stripe.

Comment: Hi, is a `ReadWriteLock` faster in this specific scenario then, you think? Also, can I use something different than a `ReadWriteLock`? In my case it's actually a `HashMap`, but I need to do a lot of work on it, so even a `ConcurrentHashMap` wouldn't fit the bill, that's why I'm thinking of falling back to a normal `HashMap` and use locks

Comment: No, I was explaining a situation where a striped lock has no advantage, and where `synchronized` is still a viable option.

Comment: Oh OK I see sorry. In my case it's a hash map, so yea, a lock can do it

Comment: `ConcurrentHashMap` uses striping internally.

Comment: Right, but as I'm saying I can't do an atomic update to the map in my real-life example. I need to do non-atomic operations, so I'll need a lock in that case, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, of course, and since a striped lock can be used to only lock a part of the map, it should be slightly faster.

Answer (score 0):

Let me put in this way. Say you have 1000 instances of a class, and you have 1000 threads trying to accesses those instances. Each instance will acquire a lock for each thread. So 1000 locks which will lead to huge memory consumption. In this case stripped locks could come handy.

But in normal case where you have a singleton class you may not need stripped locks and can go ahead and use synchronized keyword.

So, i hope i answered when to use what.

Answer (score -2):

Use a `ConcurrentHashMap` so you won't have to do any of your own synchronizing.

Comment: Read my question, I stated that: `BTW, I know I could use a simple ConcurrentHashMap here, but I'm adding the example code to make sure you understand my question.`